# typedi constructor injection return undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, dependency-injection

I'am using typedi in a Node (express) project.
I can't understand why, in my service class, the injection works fine as property injection but not as constructor injection.

This works:

```
@Service()
export default class AuthService {
  @Inject("logger") private logger
  @Inject("eventEmitter")
  private eventEmitter!: EventEmitter;
   
  constructor(

  ) {}
}
```

While this is not working:

```
@Service()
export default class AuthService {
  @Inject("logger") private logger
  @Inject("eventEmitter")
  private eventEmitter!: EventEmitter;
   
  constructor(
      @Inject("logger") private logger,
      @Inject("eventEmitter") private eventEmitter: EventEmitter
  ) {}
}
```

As an example, I use the logger and the emitter as follows:

```
  public async SignUp(
    userInputDTO: IUserInputDTO
  ): Promise<{ user: IUser; token: string }> {
    try {
      //some code
      this.logger.silly("Hashing password");
      const hashedPassword = await argon2.hash(userInputDTO.password, { salt });
      this.logger.silly("Creating user db record");
      this.eventEmitter.emit(userEvent.signUp);
      //some code

      return {
        user: { },
        token: "myToken",
      };
    } catch (e) {
      this.logger.error(e);
      throw e;
    }
  }
```

In the first case it works as expected , but in the second case, this.eventEmitter and this.logger are undefined.

As a side note:

- there aren't circular dependencies
- I imported 'reflect-metadata', in fact the decorators work fine if they are placed on properties and not in the constructor's parameters
- typedi, unless for this problem works fine. I can use Container#get , Container#set without any problem

Answer (score 0):

In the 2nd code snippet, you're already decorating `AuthService` with `@Service()`, which should be enough.

So change it to this and give it a try:

```
@Service()
export default class AuthService {

  constructor(
      private logger: YOU_NEED_A_TYPE_HERE,
      private eventEmitter: EventEmitter
  ) {}
}
```

Just make sure to change `YOU_NEED_A_TYPE_HERE` with the actual type of the logger, otherwise it won't work.

And then you should have your `logger` and `eventEmitter` references available:

```
public async SignUp(
    userInputDTO: IUserInputDTO
  ): Promise<{ user: IUser; token: string }> {
    try {
    
    // logger and eventEmitter should have the right values
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I added the type because I think it's better to make it explicit. Anyway it started working even without the explicit type. Check my answer if interested

Comment: Yes. As per typedi docs, you need both flags set to true inside `tsconfig.json` (i.e. "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
"experimentalDecorators": true).

Answer (score 0):

It started working, but I'm not sure what caused it.

- I worked on another machine with a newer node version (the example in this question was ran on node12 while it started working with node16).
- I added a line in the `tsconfig.json` that was missing.

  "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,

while `"experimentalDecorators": true` was already there.

Maybe it's time to setup a small container to test it in different node versions.

As a side note, it seems that adding explicit type to the constructor parameter to inject is not strictly required (but anyway suggested). Also the `@Inject` decorator seems also to be unnecessary as long as the class is already decorated with `@Service`

Answer (score 0):

In the first container.get, assign as arrow function.
example:

```
const userController = ()=>container.get<IUserController>(UserController);

router.get("/user", (req, res) => userController().getAllUsers(req, res));
```